# AngularJS - changing expression dinamically with input options

Tags: angularjs, shopping-cart

I am building an app where the prices of items should be displayed in different currencies. For the shopping cart, I am using an angular directive, [NgCart](http://ngcart.snapjay.com/docs) where I need to pass the quantity and price of each item. This directive has an isolate scope, so I cannot use a filter to switch currencies, but to pass the different prices directly from the scope. I just can pass the data from one scope inside the directive (the data from `name in names`).

What I would like to do is that the price displayed would change when the corresponding option is chosen in a input options element, and that by switching it, the price passed to the directive would also change (to the chosen currency). I have been trying to achieve it with ng-options, but something is not working. My html goes like this:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl" ng-app="myApp">
  <select ng-options="price.currency for price in names" ng-model="currency"></select>  
  <div ng-repeat="name in names">
    The price of {{name.toy}} is {{name.price[0].amount}} {{name.price[0].symb}}
    <ngcart-addtocart name="{{name.toy}}" price="{{name.price[0].priceUSD}}">  
        <p1>Add to Cart</p1>
    </ngcart-addtocart>
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.names = [{
      "toy": "Buzz Lightyear",
      "price": [
          {"currency":"usd","amount":199,"symb": "$"},
          {"currency":"eur","amount": 179,"symb": "€"}
      ]
    },
    {
      "toy": "Woody",
      "price": [
          {"currency":"usd","amount":179,"symb": "$"},
          {"currency":"eur","amount": 169,"symb": "€"}
      ]
    }]; 
 });
```

You can see a working JSfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Joe82/ynj2u6x2/2/) Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** Updated [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OO5GBUbCpD41ZpJJbtfw?p=preview) with the ng-cart directive, the remaining problem is that with the solution provided by Iulian, I cannot pass the currency symbol, hence I cannot display the correct unit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with your code.

1. First of all, your usage of `ngOptions` is not correct. You use `for price in names`, and thus obtain as a `price` each object from your names, which is `{"toy": ..., "price": []}` object. Instead, I would suggest you create another variable that will hold the available currencies, for instance:

```
$scope.currencies = [
  {currency: 'usd', symb: '$'},
  {currency: 'eur', symb: '€'}
];
```

2. You won't get the updated price in your directive, because you always are passing to it the first element of your price: `price="{{name.price[0].priceUSD}}"`. Instead, you need to obtain it dynamically, based on the selected currency. For this, you could create a function similar to the one below, that would return you the price given the currency:

```
$scope.getPriceInCurrency = function (item, currency) {
  var priceInCurrency = 0;
  item.price.forEach(function(price) {
    if (price.symb === currency) {
      priceInCurrency = price.amount;
    }
  });
  return priceInCurrency;
};
```

Now, when you display the options and want to show the corresponding price, use the function from above to obtain it:

```
The price of {{name.toy}} is {{getPriceInCurrency(name, currency)}} {{currency}}
```

And you can omit the `{{}}` braces when passing your values to the `ngcartAddtocart` directive, as these are not required here.

Here is a [fork](http://jsfiddle.net/zs3jyv39/2/) of your fiddle with a working example.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the "numeric conversion" works fine both outside and inside the directive. But I am not able to show the currency symbol inside the directive (as `{{selectedCurrency}}` is an scope that is outside the isolated directive). The only additional data that can be passed inside the directive is the data taken from  `name in names`, I wonder if it would be possible to display the currency symbol based just on that data (that is, without using `$scope.currencies`). Thanks!

Comment: @Joe82 use then the form from your original post. Just provide the first price list instead of all items: `ng-options="price.currency for price in names[0].price"`

Comment: Not sure if this is what you mean, I got the conversion working, but both items showing the same price: http://jsfiddle.net/Joe82/zs3jyv39/3/

Comment: The problem is that I still cannot access the currency symbol from inside the directive, so I can change the number, but not display the correct unit. I made a plunkr with the ngCart directive, so it is clearer what I mean http://plnkr.co/edit/OO5GBUbCpD41ZpJJbtfw?p=preview (In the blue underlined link the number has not unit)

Comment: I'm on my phone now and don't have access to any computer until Tuesday. Will be able to take a look at it only then.

Comment: No problem, thanks for the input. I will update my post as well with the plunker.

Comment: Hello @Joe82! Hope you are doing well. I looked through your plunker. Because you have an isolated scope in your `ngcartAddtocart` directive, you indeed don't have access to the `selectedCurrency`, but the easiest way to get access to it is to pass it along with other parameters into the directive's scope using a `currency` attribute, for instance. here is a [fork](http://plnkr.co/edit/FKnkPv4mvntXUanmGyGj?p=preview) of your plunker with a working example.

Comment: Thanks for all the effort, it works perfectly for what I asked in the plunker. Unfortunately it doesn't work for the other parts of the directive (as it doesn't update the total prices when changing the currency, it only affects it "before adding to cart", but I will probably build a filter with the way you showed me to pass another scope to the directive (and I post it here for the posterity). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since the names is an array object it is getting confused to take whether names[0] or names[1].

```
 <select ng-options="item.currency for item in names[1].price" ng-model="curr"></select>
```

So if you create a separate array for currency lookup then the problem is solved.

```
 <select ng-options="item as item.currency for item in currencyLookup" ng-model="selected"></select>
 $scope.currencyLookup=[
 {"currency":"usd","symb": "$"},
 {"currency":"eur","symb": "€"}
 ]
```

Comment: Hi, as the directive ngcart-addtocart that I use for my shopping cart is isolated, I would need to just use the content of `name in names`, as it is the only additional data that I can pass inside the directive. So I would need to do it without using an additional scope. Thanks for the approach!